# PayPal sandbox new interface not returning post parameters

Tags: paypal, sandbox

Whenever I navigate to the PayPal sandbox for a transaction, I see the new PayPal sandbox interface because of which I am unable to make transactions. Because the new interface does not return the post parameters after the transaction.

The PayPal new interface is **visible on production** as well, and the same problem is happening there, when the user completes the transaction, PayPal does not return post parameters to our site, therefore we are unable to log the transaction in our database.

The new PayPal interface:
[image: The new sandbox interface]

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with the new PayPal interface, also mentioned in developer community forum on their website. Many of the users are having problems for the past one month, and PayPal  is still working on it to resolve the issue.